# Putty on Virtual Box Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, putty

I'm trying to get PuTTY working on Ubuntu virtual box but it isn't working. I looked at the other post and it said to switch to bridged adapter which I did, and to no avail did it work. I tried updating the virtual box only driver for windows, but again no solution.

Comment: What's the host and what's the guest? and did you install an ssh server on the machine you want to connect to? Neither Windows nor Ubuntu has an ssh server installed by default.

Comment: PuTTY is an ssh client. Is there any reason for you to use exactly PuTTY? Ubuntu has numerous other ssh clients.

Comment: @rechengehirn He is probably using Windows. Of course, there are ports ofOpenSSH server and client, but PuTTY is the more popular client for Windows, mostly because it provides a sort of user friendly GUI to configure everything necessary. It's just how it turned out to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, your description is so vague that I can only guess what you mean. You have a Windows host with VirtualBox installed and set up a guest machine that is running Ubuntu. You want to connect to that machine from the host via SSH, by using PuTTY, the most popular remote terminal client on Windows. Is that right?

For that to work you need to have the SSH server package installed in the guest system (`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`). You should also [configure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) the ssh server, so that you know which port to use to connect to the server and which authentication method to use (using you user password is fine as long as you're just trying things out), at least. Second step is to configure port forwarding between host and guest OS. The default network configuration uses NAT, which is - contrary to outdated information - fine, just click port forwarding and set up a rule.

Here is an example for connecting to a webserver running in a virtual machine. I can access the websever in the VM listening at port 80 with a browser from the host system by visiting the address consisting of host IP and host port. Note: I've chosen port 8080 because the host is running a webserver too.

[image]